# How to extracted specific information such as cost and name of a product?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

But I facing problem to extract data from bs4 tag and i am not able to extract only the product name and cost[image: i am not able to extract exact exact 159995(without rupee sign and commas)]

same goes with the name of the product not able to extract name of the product[image]

I tried using indexing but that failed since it is a tag I have also used `.getText()` and `.get_text()` and tried converting into str and append into `list` that also failed and not able to get exact info required.

I am not able to extract exact 159995(without rupee sign and commas) in first image and product name in second image

Comment: Welcome to SO - Question could be improved, so that we can reproduce your issue more easily. May take a read: How to create [mcve] and replace images by code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example it should be the following, cause there is only one tag in your `ResultSet`:

```
soup.select_one('.BNuCI').get_text(strip=True)
```

Else you have to iterate your `ResultSet`:

```
for e in soup.select('.BNuCI'):
    print(e.get_text(strip=True))
```

---

Based on your comment:

It is the same way for the cost and you could extract with `regex` e.g. the numbers only:

```
import re
cost = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', soup.select_one('.YOURCLASSVALUES').get_text(strip=True)))
```

Comment: this for loop solved my second problem and I got product name but first problem remains the same

Comment: Simply adapt the example and extract numbers via regex.